# PHP json_decode() not decoding JSON array

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON string in my database such as this...

```
a:1:{s:26:"abcdefghi@jklmnopqrstu.com";s:26:"abcdefghi@jklmnopqrstu.com";}
```

After I fetch it from the database I use the following...

```
$my_array = json_decode($row2['json_data']);
```

The problem is that I'm not getting any array from `$my_array`. What am I doing wrong?

I've also tried the following...

```
$my_array = json_decode($row2['json_data'],true);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's not a JSON string. That's a serialized array. You need to do the following:

```
$my_array = unserialize($row2['json_data']);
```

Comment: I had to wait 14 minutes and then had to leave, yeah not a problem, thanks again.